# How to put html in django template variables?

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates, escaping

I want to put in pieces of html in template variables. Something like this:

```
>>>t = django.template.Template("<ul>{{ title }}<\ul>: {{ story }}")
>>>c = django.template.Context({"title":"This is the title",r"Line 1.<br />Line 2."})
>>>print t.render(c)
<ul>This is the title<\ul>: Line 1.&lt;br /&gt;Line 2.
```

I expected an output something like this:

```
<ul>This is the title<\ul>: Line 1.<br />Line 2.
```

How can I put in HTML within the template variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [safe](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#safe) filter, e.g.:

> > > t = django.template.Template("{{ title|safe }}<\ul>: {{ story|safe }}")

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`safe`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#safe) filter to inhibit encoding.